# How to run app as a transparent window non-fullscreen

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

In Visual Studio i created a blank application, when running on my device i get a full screen app.

I want a partial screen app that's transparent, that has some transparent buttons, for example, my phone resolution is 1080x1920, the app is 300x300, like a widget but it's NOT a widget, im not trying to create a widget, im trying to create an app that launches with the size of a widget? if that makes sense.

How do i approach/accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using DialogActivity, that should work

Comment: Can i run the application as a dialog?